# On clicking on back button while on a WebView a blank Activity is opened

Tags: android, webview, back

Min version - 15,
target version - 19

I create an activity

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.md_webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Also i have overridden the back method like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // Check if the key event was the BACK key and if there's history
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"key back and HISTORY");
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        // If it wasn't the BACK key or there's no web page history, bubble up
        // to the default
        // system behavior (probably exit the activity)
        Log.d(TAG,"key back and no history");
        finish();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Problem**
When I click back on the webview opened, it takes me to a blank activity and does not call the Keydown method defined above.
On pressing back again, this time the Keydown method is called and it come to the original caller activity.

**This problem has occurred to many people. But none of those has a concrete solution.** Please let me know if anyone has found a definite solution regarding this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: code works properly on Android 4.3, "key back and no history", is there anything else that you can specify

Comment: Yes code do work. But do you get that blank activity in between the web view and our main activity when pressing back? I am working on Kitkat.

Comment: didn't get it on motog 4.4 ...check if the activity containing the webview is declared as launcher in the manifest